# Python stdin errors, copied code from pycharm wont work in CMD

Tags: python, stdin

Learning python as a beginner. I wanted to copy my code into CMD but it won't work. Here is code

```
calculation_to_units = 24
name_of_unit = "hours"


def days_to_units(number_of_days):
    if number_of_days > 0:
      return f"{number_of_days} days are {number_of_days * calculation_to_units} {name_of_unit}"
    else:
        return "Liczba dni musi być dodatnia :)"



user_input = input("Hello user, enter amount of days you want to calculate to hours\n")
user_input_number = int(user_input)

calculated_value = days_to_units(user_input_number)
print(calculated_value)
```

despite the fact that it works in Pycharm. I already checked paths. I am not able to solve this problem. When I type in python3 test.py it also says C:\Users\Borys\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe: can't open file 'C:\Users\Borys\test.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Also recieved this message "unable to initialize device prn in python"

My internet connection is so bad that it took me 10 minutes to sign up on stack overflow. Additionaly my english knowledge is too small for complex programming explainations.

Comment: Please post the code as text, not an image. Are you saying you pasted this into a python shell? That's what it looks like. Pasting code with an `input()` call can be problematic. That line where you create user_input_number was actually read by `input()` and was therefore not a code line. Since it never ran, the variable was not created.

Comment: @tdelaney I added the code here, when I run it in Pycharm and just type in 20/-10 it works normally. So what should I do to run it in Python.exe or CMD? I am following a tutorial and that is the first problem I've faced.

Comment: I think the full output like the image would be the most useful. I wanted to call your attention to the line the didn't have a `>>> ` leader to emphasize the issue, but would prefer to copy/paste.

Comment: Its also a bit confusing. You are not copying code into CMD. Perhaps you ran the python shell and then did the paste? It may be better to save the program to a .py file and run from there.

Comment: @tdelaney I tried both ways said by you. Will try to save to do the thing u said

Answer (score 0):

It can be difficult to paste code that calls `input()` into a python shell. Both the shell and the `input()` function read stdin. As soon as python reads the line with `input()`, it calls `input()` and that consumes the next line on stdin. In your case, that was a python code line intended to set a variable. That line was consumbed by `input` and was not read or executed by python. So you got a "variable not defined" error. But you would also have gotten another error because that line was also not the stuff you wanted to input.

Suppose you had the script

```
val = input("Input value: ")
i_val = int(val)
print(i_val)
```

And pasted it into the python shell

```
>>> val = input("Input value: ")
Input value: i_val = int(val)
>>> print(i_val)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'i_val' is not defined. Did you mean: 'eval'?
```

The line `i_val = int(val)` was assigned to `val` - it was not interpreted by the shell. There would be an ">>> " if it did.